# html file path folder structures

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is it possible in a directoryInfo path to search all folders for a specific folder.

For example; my folder called "Images" contains 3 folders called "1","2","3". and each of those folders contains a folder called "test"

I want to seach through all 3 folders and find the folder called test

Would i be able to do something along these lines? Assuming the * searches all folders perhaps?

```
Dim dirInfo As New DirectoryInfo("images/JobImages/*/test/")
```

Comment: 1 `DirectoryInfo` instance refers to 1 directory, but you can try `DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories("test", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`.

Answer (score 0):

You would call either `GetDirectories` or `EnumerateDirectories` on your `DirectoryInfo`, depending on exactly what you want to achieve.  `GetDirectories` will get every folder first and then return the lot as a `DirectoryInfo` array, so call that if you want every match.  `EnumerateDirectories` will traverse the folder tree as you get each one, so it is the better option if you want to stop after finding the first match, e.g.

```
Dim rootFolder As New DirectoryInfo("root folder path here")
Dim testFolder = rootFolder.EnumerateDirectories("test", SearchOption.AllDirectories).First()
```